# Настройка Сontact Form 7 в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, form, плагин

Нужно чтобы Contact Form отправлял письмо человеку (например с промо кодом) на тот емайл, что он указал при заполнении формы. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В шаблоне формы должна присутствовать строка вида
E-mail: [email* your-email]

На вкладке Письмо надо активировать "Письмо 2" и в поле Кому указать [your-email]